# ServiceLoader load from different packages

Tags: java, maven, serviceloader

I wrote a generic `ServiceLocator` using the ServiceProviderPattern.

```
public <T> List<T> locateAll(final Class<T> clazz) {
    final Iterator<T> iterator = ServiceLoader.load(clazz).iterator();
    final List<T> services = new ArrayList<T>();

    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        try {
            services.add(iterator.next());
        } catch (ServiceConfigurationError serviceError) {
            serviceError.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
    }

    return services;
}
```

It only finds services if I add the service as a dependency to the maven module where the `ServiceLocator` resists. If this service uses the `ServiceLocator` itself, I will have a cirular dependency.

I need the `ServiceLocator` to load classes from not known dependencies.